# UIImage set image withfile in caches directory

Tags: ios7, uiimageview, uiimage

I am getting nil image when i try to set image from local file path (Caches directory)
file:///......

```
NSString* localImagePath=@"file:///Users/mac/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.1/Applications/BD2135B6-5E03-4797-960E-B6C2BF2D6958/Library/Caches/myImage.jpeg"
[[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:localImagePath];
```

I searched through many questions but not able to find the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be the issue was of url encoding so I solved this by getting the caches directory path

```
   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   NSString *cacheDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
   NSString *localImagePath = [cacheDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myImage.jpeg"];
   [[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:localImagePath];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)saveImage {
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedImage.png"];
UIImage *image = imageView.image; // imageView is my image from camera
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
[imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];   
}
```

Comment: I dont think it is related to my question